# What is the relationship between Spring Boot and the Maven pom.xml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I use maven to build spring boot applications. I know that the maven spring-boot dependencies have annotations (such as `@AutoConfiguration` or `@Condition*`). At what point in the `SpringApplication.run` method in the main class does it actually read from the `pom.xml` file? I'm stepping through the code line by line and I can't figure out at what point does Spring Boot interact with the `pom.xml` file.

The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` enables auto-cofiguration of the Application Context based on jar files in the classpath and user-defined beans, so presumably the pom.xml eventually gets added as a source and the annotations in the dependencies are read when the auto-configuration state is running, but I can't figure out where or when it does so.

Comment: There is no relation. Maven is a build tool. Spring is an app framework. The app code is totally unaware of the existence of maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpringApplication.run` doesn't read the `pom.xml` file, it works at a higher level of abstraction. The `pom.xml` file is used by your IDE or by the `mvn` command line application to download dependencies and configure your applications classpath.

By the time that `SpringApplication.run` is called, the classpath is fully configured but `SpringApplication` itself isn't aware about how this was done.

Auto-configuration occurs by searching the all jars on the classpath looking for a files named `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` (if you're using a recent version). Once these files have been found, the classes listed within them are loaded and used for configuration.

If you want to step though the code, you can set a breakpoint at `AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(...)` and see the auto-configuration candidate classes get found. The exact auto-configurations that get applied will depend on the `@Condition...` annotations on them.